# Method 'method' call adds extra word 'Kernel' in output

Tags: ruby, methods

1) While a `Method` object for the following `g`:

```
class Word < Array
  def g
    puts "JJ"
  end
end

w = Word.new([4, 6])
```

has inspection like this,

```
w.method(:g) # => #<Method: Word#g>
```

why and how does the `Method` object for the `class` have `(Kernel)` in the inspection as below?

```
w.method(:class) # => #<Method: Word(Kernel)#class>
Word.method(:class) # => #<Method: Class(Kernel)#class>
```

2) Why and how does the inspection of `Method` object for `method` have `Class` in place of `Word`'s superclass `Object` like the following?

```
# => #<Method: Object#class>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Method `class` seems to come from `Kernel` module. It's documented in `Object` class though, as `Kernel` documentation says (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html).
2. It's because the object `Word` is of class `Class`, its superclass has nothing to do with it in this case.

Comment: Just to add to this, `Kernel` is a module that provides the `class` method, however the instance methods of `Kernel` are _documented_ in class `Object`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html